# How can I restore a specific version of my google sheet by using a google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a button that restore a specific version of my google sheet when I press it by using a google script.

The reason is that I would like to clear my google sheet but to set up the same format and everything as the original version in case someone else changes the format of the cells.

I though I could add a button and restore the version to the original before some enters any data.

Any idea about how to do this by using a script? (I'm open to suggestions)

Thank you!

Comment: You need to look into Google drive api revisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can restore a version using a Google Script as the process of running a script updates the current version anyway.

You could write a script that cleared all of the editable cells (and set any formatting back to default) and add this to a custom menu so that you could reset the sheet at the press of a button.

This might achieve the same result you are looking for.

Here is one I have used before but it is obviously specific to my needs.

```
function clear() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Deleting');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  range.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue('Copy and paste Data here')
   .setBackground('yellow');
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  sheet.setFrozenRows(0);
  sheet.deleteColumns(2,maxColumns-1);
  sheet.deleteRows(2,maxRows-1);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Deleted');
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
   .createMenu('Custom Menu') 
   .addItem('Clear','clear')
   .addToUi();
}
```

A more specific example for you might be:

```
function clear() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Deleting');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.getRange('A26:E30').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('A33:E37').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('A40:E44').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D2:D3').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D5:D9').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D12:D16').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('A19').setValue(false);
  sheet.getRange('C19').setValue(false);
}
```

I may have missed some sections so you will need to adapt for you usage.  If you want to use the clear button that you have already created then you can right click it and assign the clear function to it so that every time you click clear it will execute the above script. This may not be the most elegant solution but it should work for your needs.

Comment: Hi Brett thank you so much for you answer but how could I set the default values of my sheet, some cells have conditional formatting and other ones has data validation? I just want the format from the cells in white (where the user is supposed to enter the data)

This is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10DrFHUh-bf69a-JB__aPd1jEY2X1v1DJj8jbzf2DyIY/edit#gid=1579104236

Comment: Instead of range.clear() you could use range.clearContent() this will only clear the typing and not the formatting

Comment: I have edited my answer with a more specific example for you based on the link you provided.  If I missed any sections you can copy and paste the sheet.getRange line and change the cell references that you need to clear

Comment: If this helped could you please accept the answer or let me know how I can assist further?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is copy paste from another sheet:

```
      function Restore() {
              var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('detination sheet id');
              var destSheet = destination.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
              var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('source sheet id');
              var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

              destSheet.clearContents();
              if(destSheet.getMaxRows()>sourceSheet.getMaxRows())
              {
              destSheet.deleteRows(sourceSheet.getMaxRows(), (destSheet.getMaxRows() - sourceSheet.getMaxRows()));
              }
              if(destSheet.getMaxColumns()>sourceSheet.getMaxColumns())
              {
              destSheet.deleteColumns(sourceSheet.getMaxColumns(), (destSheet.getMaxColumns() - sourceSheet.getMaxColumns()));
              }

              var copySheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(destination);
              copySheet.getDataRange().copyTo(destSheet.getDataRange());
              destination.deleteSheet(copySheet);
         }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. What I did was to format every single range or cell needed with a specific format. This worked fine but it'a time consuming and you need to think about every single detail hehe.

I might try your solution later on Hakan.